# WordPress :: xmlrpc.php Attack redirect to homepage

Tags: wordpress, nginx, xml-rpc, ddos

i am getting more than 8k constant xmlrpc attack on my wordpress website. from the below source:

```
185.106.92.53 - - [07/Apr/2016:01:42:32 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)" "-"
```

my doubt is that can i redirect the POST method into GET and with the link to my homepage. for ex: by the above attack an attacker will be redirected to my http://mydomain.co/

if there is any method then please let me know.. i am using nginx server.
thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean to redirect a specific remote IP address?

Comment: no, i mean every POST request coming for /xmlrpc.php to be redirected to GET /index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, even if you adjusted the request, this is likely an automated script carrying out these requests and you'll have no benefit doing this.

Since your using nginx, I'd recommend setting up something like:

```
 location = /xmlrpc.php {
     deny all;
     access_log off;
 }
```

OR blocking the attacker like: `iptables -A INPUT -s 185.106.92.53 -j DROP` if it's a single IP attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Apache to ignore this request adding to .htaccess

Order Allow,Deny
deny from all

Read this article for further information:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-prevent-denial-of-service-attacks-against-xmlrpcphp

Comment: please take time to read my question. I am using Nginx sxerver.